# Wierd active record behavior in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Have a simple Lead model and trying to clean out the `\\t` and `\\n` from a string

```
class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base


attr_accessible :offense_description

def clean_offense_description
  if self.offense_description
    k = self.offense_description.gsub("\\t", '').gsub("\\n", '')
    self.update_attributes({:offense_description => k},:without_protection => true)
  end
end
```

When I execute this i get the update over and over and over

```
irb(main):004:0> l.clean_offense_description
(58.7ms)  BEGIN
(59.7ms)  UPDATE `leads` SET `offense_description` = '{\"1\":{\"description\":\"Some Description }\",\"code\":\"234\",\"agency\":\"SO JASPER COUNTY - CARTHAGE\"}}', `updated_at` = '2013-12-04 22:27:31' WHERE `leads`.`id` = 440919
```

Offense_description is spelled wrong, and is a `JSON` string.

---

When i forcibly close the loop of updates here is the output

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: IRB::Abort: abort then interrupt!: UPDATE `leads` SET `offense_description` = '{\"1\":{\"description\":\"Non-Support\",\"code\":\"500\",\"agency\":\"SO\"}}', `updated_at` = '2013-12-05 05:06:29' WHERE `leads`.`id` = 440919
from /home/talos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb.rb:420:in `raise'
from /home/talos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb.rb:420:in `irb_abort'
from /home/talos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb.rb:607:in `signal_handle'
from /home/talos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb.rb:392:in `block in start'
from /home/talos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@LegalLeads/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `call'
from /home/talos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@LegalLeads/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `query'
from /home/talos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@LegalLeads/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `block in execute'
from /home/talos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@LegalLeads/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
from /home/talos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@LegalLeads/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
from /home/talos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@LegalLeads/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
from /home/talos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@LegalLeads/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `execute'
from /home/talos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@LegalLeads/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:211:in `execute'
from /home/talos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@LegalLeads/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:238:in `exec_delete'
from /home/talos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@LegalLeads/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:96:in `update'
from /home/talos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@LegalLeads/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in `update'
from /home/talos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@LegalLeads/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:359:in `update'
... 1622 levels...
from /home/talos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
from /home/talos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:233:in `loop'
from /home/talos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:233:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
from /home/talos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:232:in `catch'
from /home/talos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:232:in `each_top_level_statement'
from /home/talos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb.rb:488:in `eval_input'
from /home/talos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb.rb:397:in `block in start'
from /home/talos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb.rb:396:in `catch'
from /home/talos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb.rb:396:in `start'
from /home/talos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@LegalLeads/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /home/talos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@LegalLeads/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /home/talos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@LegalLeads/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/talos/Link to RubymineProjects/legalleads/script/rails:6:in `require'
from /home/talos/Link to RubymineProjects/legalleads/script/rails:6:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'Maybe IRB bug!
```

Comment: Try using slashes in the `gsub` instead of double-quotes:  `self.offense_description.gsub(/\\t/, '').gsub(/\\n/, '')`

Comment: Tried and same error.  Will add some output when i forcibly close it to the top.

Comment: You didn't by any chance put `clean_offense_description` into a *_update or *_save hook in the model? This would explain why you get an infinite update loop as you're calling update_attributes from within the method

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`squish`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/squish).

For example:

```
k = self.offense_description.squish
```

Comment: Would squish affect anything with it being JSON?

Comment: It won't affect your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
self.offense_description.gsub(/\t/, '').gsub(/\n/, '')
```